# How can i see my devices external USB storage in android studio

Tags: usb, file-transfer, file-management, usb-on-the-go, android-studio

I'm currently creating an application that aims to automatically move a file between the folder of a USB device and an internal folder.

I have the code that moves the files between two folders working on an emulator, however I cannot configure the code to work on a live machine as when I connect my device to Android Studio the Device File Explorer fails to display the USB device.

I have the USB device connected to my Android Device and my Android Device is connected to Android Studio over Wi-Fi. My primary concern is detecting my USB storage in Studio explorer, if this is not possible, any advice on transferring files to external USB devices is appreciated.

(I am aware that interaction with files on a USB device will void my app from ever getting on the app store, this is purely a non-commercial, internal app)